# How to make href link dynamic inside the gridview ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, webforms

I have been trying this but cannot get it done.

I have this link in item template.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tender's Details <br/> ٹینڈر کی تفصیلات">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <a href='<%#Eval("Url")%>/forms/general/print.aspx?OfficeID=<%# SharedUtility.EncryptURL(Eval("OfficeID").ToString()) %>&NITNo=<%# SharedUtility.EncryptURL(Eval("NITNo").ToString()) %>' class='<%#Eval("IsPublished").ToString()=="False"?"":"hidden"%>' target="_blank">                                           
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

in href the link **/print.aspx** should be dynamic such as if OfficeID =1 then it should be /print.aspx else **/print222.aspx**.

That's all.

I tried modifying it but results in many other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a ternary operator like you do with the `class`?

```
<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("OfficeID")) == 1 ? "print.aspx" : "print222.aspx" %>
```